# IOS/ARKIT - How to do previous and next buttons which changes 3D model with animations when clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I want to display a 3D model like a slide show. When you click on next, the next one comes up does its animation for few seconds.... then next.... and this continues in tandem of changing UILabel text.

PressedNextbtn ---> (On ARSCNView) New 3D model displays ---> PressedNextbtn ---> (On ARSCNView) New 3D model displays --->

Also I would like to add a previous button so it can go back as well. Please check out the image below for further information if this is unclear.

So  :

1. Starts with idle 3D model
2. User presses next
3. Changes the 3d model with inherent animation playing and laos changes UI LABEL
4. The above 3D model changes every time user presses next
5. Also an ability to go back to previous if necessary.

note : I have figured out the UILabel, now I need to run the 3D model slide show unto the system seen in the image. I hope this clarifies everything.

```
@IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    displayNext()
```

***//DISPLAYs NEXT 3D model inherent ANIMATION from array***
    }

```
@IBAction func prevPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    getPrevious()
```

***//DISPLAY Previous 3D model with inherent ANIMATION***
    }

```
func displayNext()  {
    guard currentIndex < myArray.count else {
       // timer.invalidate() //if you don't want to repeat showing the images you can invalidate the timer.
        currentIndex = 0 // add this if you want to repeat showing the image
        return
    }
    allArray.append(myArray[currentIndex])
    sildeText.text = myArray[currentIndex]
    currentIndex += 1



}

func getPrevious() {
    if allArray.count > 1 {
        allArray.removeLast()
        sildeText.text = allArray.last
    }
    else {
        sildeText.text = allArray.last
    }
}
```

Please check the app structure out..the 3D model is not properly positioned yet.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more context. What 3D model are you talking about? ARKit? SpriteKit?

Comment: Hi Duncan, Thank you for replying I have added a picture above..Its for ArKit... I would like to change text together with 3D model which has one animation.

Comment: So add an ARKit tag to your question, and explain more about your 3D model and what you want to do to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to achieve this behavior,

1. Add `UIPageviewController` and in the content add your UILabel and 3D model and change the page index on 'Next' or 'Previous' button click.
2. Use Horizontal `UIScrollView` and change the frame along with UILabel and 3D model on 'Next' or 'Previous' button click.

I would prefer using `UIPageviewController`,

In ViewController.m,

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController () <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIPageViewController *PageViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrPageTitles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrPageDescription;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        
    // Create page view controller
    self.PageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.PageViewController.dataSource = self;
    self.PageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.shouldShowPageController = YES;
    
    [self addChildViewController:PageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:PageViewController.view];
    [self.PageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

#pragma mark - Page View Datasource Methods

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentVC *) viewController).pageIndex;
    
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:([self.arrPageTitles count] - 1)];
    }
    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentVC *) viewController).pageIndex;
    
    if (index == NSNotFound){
        return nil;
    }
    index++;
    if (index == [self.arrPageTitles count]){
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

#pragma mark - PageContent View Controller Method

- (PageContentVC *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    if (([self.arrPageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.arrPageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PageContentVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    PageContentVC *pageContentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContent"];
    pageContentViewController.title = self.arrPageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.description = self.arrPageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;    
    return pageContentViewController;
}
@end
```

here, PageContentVC is the content view controller inside the `UIPageviewController`

Comment: Hi Aditya thanks for the answer but I am not familiar with obj c. I jsut added the app wire frame picture can you please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set data to object in viewDidLoad() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
           super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: strPhotoName)
        lblTitle.text = strTitle
    }
```

**Implement UIPageViewController**

Create two NSArray to store Image title and Image name

```
var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
        var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()
```

**Variable Initialisation**
Initialise Array.

Set data source for PageViewController.

Set first page of PageViewController from viewDidLoad() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrPageTitle = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets"];
        arrPagePhoto = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];
        self.dataSource = self
        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Implement Datasource Methods**

viewControllerBeforeViewController()
Use this method to return to previous view. In this I have put a condition such that if it is first view then return nil otherwise return ViewController.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController
        var index = pageContent.pageIndex
        if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }
        index--;
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }
```

viewControllerAfterViewController
Use this method to return next view. In this I have put a condition such that if it is last view then return nil otherwise return ViewController.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController
        var index = pageContent.pageIndex
        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        index++;
        if (index == arrPageTitle.count)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }
```

**Create method for get new PageContentViewController**

getViewControllerAtIndex
When user swipe using gesture then we have to instantiate ViewController from storyboard and assign all content data of ViewController and return it.

```
func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController
    {
        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
        pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
        return pageContentViewController
    }
```